# Magento 2 Admin section 'The order confirmation email is not sent' showing

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

I am facing this issue I have started the setup of my store. In this when any customer is placing the order he is getting a confirmation email (as still today no one complains about not getting mail) but in the admin section it is showing The order confirmation email is not sent after the order id is in the order view page of the admin. [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6OMq.png)

I am not getting any way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some items that could be causing this:

Misconfiguration of email settings: Check the email settings in the Magento Admin Panel and ensure that the email address and SMTP server settings are correct. You can find this configuration under Stores > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails.

Cron job not set up or not running: The order confirmation emails are sent via a cron job. Make sure that the cron job is set up and running properly. You can check this in the Magento Admin Panel under Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Cron (Scheduled Tasks).

Email queue backlog: If there is a backlog in the email queue, it can cause a delay in sending out confirmation emails. You can check the email queue status in the Magento Admin Panel under Marketing > Communications > Email Queue.

Spam filters blocking emails: Some email clients or servers may have aggressive spam filters that may block the order confirmation emails. Check if the email is not landing in the spam folder.

Third-party extensions conflicting with email sending: Third-party extensions or custom code can sometimes interfere with the email sending process. Try disabling any recently installed extensions and check if the issue persists.

It's important to note that even if the customers are receiving the confirmation emails, there could still be an issue with the email sending process that is causing this error in the Magento 2 admin section. It's recommended to investigate and resolve this issue to ensure proper functionality of your store's email system.

Comment: I have checked by placing a test order and didn't get any mail and also not getting forget password mail. So I think so mail system is stopped working. In admin, the client hasn't used any SMTP module to send the email. So how can I find what is the root cause behind email not sending?

Comment: @savitanagdev 

Make sure that the SMTP configuration settings in your Magento store are correct. These settings can typically be found in the admin panel under 'Stores' > 'Configuration' > 'Advanced' > 'System' > 'Mail Sending Settings' 

Review your email logs for any errors or warnings. 

Use the built-in email testing functionality in Magento or an SMTP extension to send a test email. This will help you identify if the problem is related to email sending or email receiving.